# How to permanently enable newer version of software installed from SCL repo?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command, scl

On CentOS 6.4:

I installed a newer version of devtoolset (1.1) and was wondering how I would go about permanently setting these to be default. Right now, when I ssh into my server running CentOS 6, I have to run this command `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash`

I tried adding it to ~/.bashrc and simply pasting it on the very last line, without success.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` Simply source the "enable" script provided with the devtoolset. For example, with the Devtoolset 2, the command is:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable
```

or

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-2
```

Lot more efficient: no forkbomb, no tricky shell

Comment: This was applicable on centos 6.8. Just a minor change to "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/enable"

Comment: sourcing this file is still working with devtoolset-7

Comment: @datdinhquoc yes, you need to source `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable`

Comment: Just a late note on this: `scl scl_source enable gcc-toolset-11` doesn't work in zsh, only bash -- something about arrays I think. But `source /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/enable` works fine even in zsh.

Comment: `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/enable` was my savior after I updated Centos7

Answer (score 15):

An alternative of `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/enable` is

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-4
```

The above shell script `scl_source` is more elegant than using a hard coded path (may be different on another machine). However `scl_source` does less because `/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/enable` uses `scl_source` and other stuff.

To use `scl_source` you may have to upgrade package `scl-utils`

```
yum update scl-utils  # old scl-utils versions miss scl_source
```

Quick copy-paste

```
echo 'source scl_source enable devtoolset-4' >> ~/.bashrc
    # Do not forget to change the version ↑
```

---

**Source code for curious people**

An example of `scl_source` source code:
https://gist.github.com/bkabrda/6435016

The `scl_source` installed on my Red Hat 7.1

```
#!/bin/bash

_scl_source_help="Usage: source scl_source <action> [<collection> ...]

Don't use this script outside of SCL scriptlets!

Options:
    -h, --help    display this help and exit"

if [ $# -eq 0 -o $1 = "-h" -o $1 = "--help" ]; then
    echo "$_scl_source_help"
    return 0
fi


if [ -z "$_recursion" ]; then
    _recursion="false"
fi
if [ -z "$_scl_scriptlet_name" ]; then
    # The only allowed action in the case of recursion is the same
    # as was the original
    _scl_scriptlet_name=$1
fi
shift 1

if [ -z "$_scl_dir" ]; then
    # No need to re-define the directory twice
    _scl_dir=/etc/scl/conf
    if [ ! -e $_scl_dir ]; then
        _scl_dir=/etc/scl/prefixes
    fi
fi

for arg in "$@"; do
    _scl_prefix_file=$_scl_dir/$arg
    _scl_prefix=`cat $_scl_prefix_file 2> /dev/null`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Can't read $_scl_prefix_file, $arg is probably not installed."
        return 1
    fi

    # First check if the collection is already in the list
    # of collections to be enabled
    for scl in ${_scls[@]}; do
        if [ $arg == $scl ]; then
            continue 2
        fi
    done

    # Now check if the collection isn't already enabled
    /usr/bin/scl_enabled $arg > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        _scls+=($arg)
        _scl_prefixes+=($_scl_prefix)
    fi;
done

if [ $_recursion == "false" ]; then
    _i=0
    _recursion="true"
    while [ $_i -lt ${#_scls[@]} ]; do
        _scl_scriptlet_path="${_scl_prefixes[$_i]}/${_scls[$_i]}/${_scl_scriptlet_name}"
        source "$_scl_scriptlet_path"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Can't source $_scl_scriptlet_name, skipping."
        else
            export X_SCLS="${_scls[$_i]} $X_SCLS"
        fi;
        _i=$(($_i+1))
    done
    _scls=()
    _scl_prefixes=()
    _scl_scriptlet_name=""
    _recursion="false"
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash` creates a new bash shell. So when you put it in your .bashrc, it creates a new shell...which loads your .bashrc, which runs `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash`, which creates a new shell, which loads your .bashrc... Forkbomb!

You probably want something like this in your .bashrc:

```
if [ "$(gcc -dumpversion)" != "4.7.2" ]; then 
  scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
fi
```

or

```
if [ -z "$TRIEDSCLDEVTOOLSET" ]; then
  export TRIEDSCLDEVTOOLSET=true
  scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
fi
```

- the first will continue to forkbomb if devtoolset-1.1 does not contain gcc 4.7.2, and will also fail to work if your native environment has gcc 4.7.2.
- this creates a new shell, as above. So when you create your terminal window or ssh session, you will be in two bash sessions, and have to `exit` twice.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I indeed got a fork bomb and didn't understand why but that makes perfect sense. It sounds like using scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash is not the practical way to go then since I'm only going to be putting use to 4.7.2 and not the older version. Would I just need to remove the older version of devtools and do some other things to only have the one version?

Comment: If you have root privileges on the machine and never need the older version of gcc (or of the other tools in devtoolset-1.1) then yes, you may want to just install the latest gcc natively. You don't have to remove devtoolset, just don't `scl enable` it.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I've got root permissions. How do you "install" things natively? Both are installed but I have to run `scl enable` every time i open a new ssh session. I apologize for these noobish questions but I'm not sure how to go about setting the newer version as default. Is there an environment variable which I need to export in my bash profile?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how scl and devtoolset work. Devtoolset is a collection for Software Collections (SCL). SCL lets you use multiple versions of the same tool. For example, if you need GCC 4.4 and GCC 4.7 on the same machine, you can do it with SCL. GCC 4.7 isn't really installed on your system, it's in the SCL environment. Only the older version (4.4?) is really installed. To install apps natively, use your distro's package manager. On Ubuntu, this is apt-get, e.g. `sudo apt-get install gcc`. On CentOS, this is yum, e.g. `sudo yum install gcc`.

Comment: I suspect you have an old version of CentOS that doesn't have gcc4.7 in yum yet. I would do `sudo yum update && sudo yum install gcc` and check `gcc --version`. If it's not 4.7, then you probably have to use devtoolset. If you don't want to run it in SCL, you can uninstall the native gcc with `sudo yum remove gcc` and then add the devtoolset directory to your path, i.e. put `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin` in your .bashrc. That will let you type `gcc` or `g++` and get the devtoolset gcc4.7.

Comment: I initially tried going this route to install a new version of gcc but it didn't work so i resorted to finding a tutorial on how to do it manually. When i run sudo yum update I just get some output that says no package were marked for update. And then when I run sudo yum install gcc just for the heck of it, I just get output that says the latest version is installed (4.4.7 or something). This is a VPS server that I pay a hosting company, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Right, your CentOS version doesn't have gcc4.7 in yum. I'd `yum remove gcc` and add the devtoolset-1.1 bin to your path, as above.

Comment: FYI, you can list currently enabled software collections with `echo $X_SCLS`. No need to analyze gcc's version.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to locate the script mentioned in other answers is to let your package manager tell you where it lives.

This is what we run to pull in the dotnet tools on our RHEL/CentOS vagrant machines.

`source $(rpm -ql rh-dotnet20-runtime|grep -E /enable$)`

Answer (score 0):

For enabling it across systems for all users. Please make changes in "`/etc/profile`" as below:

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-2
```